# Tenses to use with "until now"

Tags: grammar

I'm confused in using 'until now.' Precisely, which tense should I use with **until now**?

- I *paid* my electric bills **until now.**
- I *have paid* my electric bills **until now.**
- I *had paid* my electric bills **until now.**

Answer (score 0):

You have *'now'* as a period which means that you are talking about all the paid bills while you are speaking the sentence. Obviously, when you want to refer to the period starting from one point **till now,** the choice is *have.* Have + past participle would denote that the process is completed.

> I have paid my electricity bill until now.

On the other hand, the past perfect would require the time from the past.

> I had paid my electricity bills until *last year.*

Comment: _Had paid_ could work in a narrative, where "Now" can refer to the story time; but in ordinary contexts it is inconsistent with "now" as you say.